# Exclude folders from TrueImage backups

Tags: backup, acronis, trueimage

Acronis TrueImage 11 Home is advertised to be able to exclude Files *and Folders* from the backup. But when creating a scheduled backup task it seems to only allow to exclude Files (by extension or name). How and where do I specify to exclude whole folders + subfolders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to make sure to include the tailing "\" when you're defining your exlude list (in the Files to Exclude screen) in order for it to recognize the entry as a folder and not just a file.  Page 34-35 in the [TrueImage Manual](http://download.acronis.com/pdf/TrueImage2009_ug.en.pdf).